# Easier way to plot the cumulative frequency distribution in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for an easier way to draw the cumulative distribution line in ggplot.

I have some data whose histogram I can immediately display with

```
qplot (mydata, binwidth=1);
```

I found a way to do it at http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/quantitative-data/cumulative-frequency-graph but it involves several steps and when exploring data it's time consuming.

Is there a way to do it in a more straightforward way in ggplot, similar to how trend lines and confidence intervals can be added by specifying options?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a built in `ecdf()` function in R which should make things easier. Here's some sample code, utilizing `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
data(iris)

## Ecdf over all species
iris.all <- summarize(iris, Sepal.Length = unique(Sepal.Length), 
                            ecdf = ecdf(Sepal.Length)(unique(Sepal.Length)))

ggplot(iris.all, aes(Sepal.Length, ecdf)) + geom_step()

#Ecdf within species
iris.species <- ddply(iris, .(Species), summarize,
                            Sepal.Length = unique(Sepal.Length),
                            ecdf = ecdf(Sepal.Length)(unique(Sepal.Length)))

ggplot(iris.species, aes(Sepal.Length, ecdf, color = Species)) + geom_step()
```

**Edit** I just realized that you want cumulative frequency. You can get that by multiplying the ecdf value by the total number of observations:

```
iris.all <- summarize(iris, Sepal.Length = unique(Sepal.Length), 
                            ecdf = ecdf(Sepal.Length)(unique(Sepal.Length)) * length(Sepal.Length))

iris.species <- ddply(iris, .(Species), summarize,
                            Sepal.Length = unique(Sepal.Length),
                            ecdf = ecdf(Sepal.Length)(unique(Sepal.Length))*length(Sepal.Length))
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but there's one thing I can't quite figure out.  In the `ecdf(Sepal.Length)(unique(Sepal.Length))` bit, what's happening?  I understand that it's extracting concrete values from the `ecdf` object, but I don't remember ever seeing that (x)(y) notation before... can you help me understand that?  Thanks!

Comment: @MattParker `ecdf()` returns a function so that notation is evaluating the returned function at the unique values of `Sepal.Length`.

Answer (score 62):

The new version of ggplot2 (0.9.2.1) has a built-in [stat_ecdf()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/stat_ecdf.html) function which let's you plot cumulative distributions very easily.

```
qplot(rnorm(1000), stat = "ecdf", geom = "step")
```

Or

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100, 0, 3), rnorm(100, 0, 10)),
             g = gl(2, 100))
ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = g)) + stat_ecdf()
```

Code samples from ggplot2 documentation.

Answer (score 21):

Even easier:

```
qplot(unique(mydata), ecdf(mydata)(unique(mydata))*length(mydata), geom='step')
```

Comment: Cool, but so succinct I am having a hard time translating to a ggplot command that I can use to set the title and axis labels.

Comment: I suppose I can use main, xlab, ylab.

Comment: how does that interact with facets?