# ECDF on the same plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame, which after applying the melt function looks similar to:

```
 var       val
1 a 0.6133426
2 a 0.9736237
3 b 0.6201497
4 b 0.3482745
5 c 0.3693730
6 c 0.3564962
```

..................

The initial dataframe had 3 columns with the column names, a,b,c and their associated values.
I need to plot on the same graph, using ggplot the associated ecdf for each of these columns (ecdf(a),ecdf(b),ecdf(c)) but I am failing in doing this. I tried:

```
p<-ggplot(melt_exp,aes(melt_exp$val,ecdf,colour=melt_exp$var))
pg<-p+geom_step()
```

But I am getting an error :arguments imply differing number of rows: 34415, 0.

Does anyone have an idea on how this can be done? The graph should look similar to the one returned by plot(ecdf(x)), not a step-like one.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that you should never have a `$` inside `aes`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12762919/350713 This is probably currently the best way to plot CDFs with ggplot2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My first thought was to try to use `stat_function`, but since `ecdf` returns a function, I couldn't get that working quickly. Instead, here's a solution the requires that you attach the computed values to the data frame first (using Ramnath's example data):

```
library(plyr) # function ddply()
mydf_m <- ddply(mydf_m, .(variable), transform, ecd = ecdf(value)(value))

ggplot(mydf_m,aes(x = value, y = ecd)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = variable, colour = variable))
```

[image]

If you want a smooth estimate of the ECDF you could also use `geom_smooth` together with the function `ns()` from the `spline` package:

```
library(splines) # function ns()
ggplot(mydf_m, aes(x = value, y = ecd, group = variable, colour = variable)) + 
    geom_smooth(se = FALSE, formula = y ~ ns(x, 3), method = "lm")
```

[image]

As noted in a comment above, as of version 0.9.2.1, ggplot2 has a specific stat for this purpose: [stat_ecdf](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/stat_ecdf.html). Using that, we'd just do something like this:

```
ggplot(mydf_m,aes(x = value)) + stat_ecdf(aes(colour = variable))
```

Comment: @Joran-I have got a beautiful graph. Thanks. It was pretty good  without the smoothing, but now it's perfect :)

Comment: oops did not see your answer joran

Comment: +1 for stat_ecdf! Good to know that.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Ramnath, approach above, you get the ecdf from ggplot2 by doing the following:

```
require(ggplot2)
mydf = data.frame(
   a = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
   b = rnorm(100, 2, 1),
   c = rnorm(100, -2, 0.5)
)

mydf_m = melt(mydf)

p0 = ggplot(mydf_m, aes(x = value)) + 
   stat_ecdf(aes(group = variable, colour = variable)) 
print(p0)
```

Comment: library(reshape) is required.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach

```
require(ggplot2)
mydf = data.frame(
  a = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  b = rnorm(100, 2, 1),
  c = rnorm(100, -2, 0.5)
)

mydf_m = melt(mydf)

p0 = ggplot(mydf_m, aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_density(aes(group = variable, colour = variable)) +
  opts(legend.position = c(0.85, 0.85))
```

Comment: This is very useful for plotting the density function on the same plot, however I was looking for something similar to :http://mikelove.wordpress.com/category/visualization/page/2/ , the black curve, not the red one. I want the cdf fucntions plotted like you did with the density functions, and I did not manage to do that