# Plotting multiple ECDFs in the same plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Similar to the question here - [ECDF on the same plot using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989015/ecdf-on-the-same-plot-using-ggplot2), but what if the number of data points differ. See example below --

```
a = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
b = rnorm(25, 2, 1)
c = rnorm(75, -2, 0.5)
```

How do I plot the ECDFs of a, b, and c in the sample plot using ggplot2?

Comment: It is no different, what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: It doesn't even allow creating the data.frame because the #rows are different

Comment: What's the problem? Either create the melted data frame directly, or, you know, `melt` works on lists too: `melt(list(a = a,b = b,c = c))`.