# Plotting cumulative counts in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are some posts about plotting cumulative densities in ggplot. I'm currently using the accepted answer from [Easier way to plot the cumulative frequency distribution in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544002/easier-way-to-plot-the-cumulative-frequency-distribution-in-ggplot) for plotting my cumulative counts. But this solution involves pre-calculating the values beforehand.

Here I'm looking for a pure ggplot solution. Let's show what I have so far:

```
x <- data.frame(A=replicate(200,sample(c("a","b","c"),1)),X=rnorm(200))
```

### ggplot's `stat_ecdf`

I can use ggplot's `stat_ecdf`, but it only plots cumulative densities:

```
ggplot(x,aes(x=X,color=A)) + geom_step(aes(y=..y..),stat="ecdf")
```

[image]

I'd like to do something like the following, but it doesn't work:

```
ggplot(x,aes(x=X,color=A)) + geom_step(aes(y=..y.. * ..count..),stat="ecdf")
```

### `cumsum` and `stat_bin`

I found an idea about using `cumsum` and `stat_bin`:

```
ggplot(x,aes(x=X,color=A)) + stat_bin(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step")
```

[image]

But as you can see, the next color doesn't start at `y=0`, but where the last color ended.

## What I ask for

What I'd like to have from best to worst:

1. Ideally a simple fix to the not working

   ```
   ggplot(x,aes(x=X,color=A)) + geom_step(aes(y=..y.. * ..count..),stat="ecdf")
   ```
2. A more complicated way to use `stat_ecdf` with counts.
3. Last resort would be to use the `cumsum` approach, since it gives worse (binned) results.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will not solve directly problem with grouping of lines but it will be workaround.

You can add three calls to `stat_bin()` where you subset your data according to `A` levels.

```
ggplot(x,aes(x=X,color=A)) +
  stat_bin(data=subset(x,A=="a"),aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step")+
  stat_bin(data=subset(x,A=="b"),aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step")+
  stat_bin(data=subset(x,A=="c"),aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step")
```

[image]

### UPDATE - solution using geom_step()

Another possibility is to multiply values of `..y..` with number of observations in each level. To get this number of observations at this moment only way I found is to precalculate them before plotting and add them to original data frame. I named this column `len`. Then in `geom_step()` inside `aes()` you should define that you will use variable `len=len` and then define `y` values as `y=..y.. * len`.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- data.frame(A=replicate(200,sample(c("a","b","c"),1)),X=rnorm(200))
library(plyr)
df <- ddply(x,.(A),transform,len=length(X))
ggplot(df,aes(x=X,color=A)) + geom_step(aes(len=len,y=..y.. * len),stat="ecdf")
```

[image]

Comment: While this works, it doesn't scale. The motivation of this question is to get more maintainable/robust code.

Answer (score 12):

You can apply `row_number` over the groups, and utilize that as the Y aesthetic in a `geom_step` or other geometry. You'll just have to sort by `X`, or the values will appear as they do in the data frame, unordered.

```
ggplot(x %>% 
         group_by(A) %>% 
         arrange(X) %>% 
         mutate(rn = row_number())) + 
  geom_step(aes(x=X, y=rn, color=A))
```

[image: Cumulative count by group]

Comment: Alternatively, can use `mutate(rn = rank(X, ties = "max"))` if you want to avoid sorting the data (although I prefer `row_number()`).

Comment: The advantage to @jdoubleyou answer is that one need not hard-code values of A!

Answer (score 2):

How about using `ave()` to get cumulative sum by group?

```
ggplot(x[order(x$X),], aes(x = X, y = ave(A == A, A, FUN = cumsum), col = A)) + geom_step()
```

[image]