# Why `cumsum` doesn't work within groups or facets in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Borrowing example from [Plotting cumulative counts in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379933/plotting-cumulative-counts-in-ggplot2)

```
x <- data.frame(A=replicate(200,sample(c("a","b","c"),1)),X=rnorm(200))
ggplot(x,aes(x=X,color=A)) + stat_bin(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step")
```

[image]

As you can see, `cumsum` work across groups & facets. I am wondering why it does that? Clearly `..count..` is done within groups, why `cumsum` is not when applied on to `..count..`? Does ggplot internally cat all `..count..` into a vector and then apply `cumsum` to it?

How to correctly resolve it without pre processing, e.g. using `plyr`?

And I don't mind `geom` is not `step`, it can be `line` or even `bar` as long as the graph is a cumulative plot.

Comment: Read `?stat_bin`. It returns a data.frame and you access one of the data.frame columns with `..count..`.

Comment: I've read ?stat_bin.And as often happens in ggplot documentation it says nothing how to get the statistical function applied by groups. The line "See _layer_" is sprinkled liberally around ggplot2 help pages and what you get at ?layer is laughably brief.

Comment: Basically, you can't. Keep in mind that one of the basic design principles of ggplot is that you manipulate your data into the right shape and _then_ call ggplot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handle this with one line of code (ddply and mutate):

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),kind=sample(c("a","b","c"),1000,replace=T),
         label=sample(1:5,1000,replace=T),attribute=sample(1:2,1000,replace=T))

dfx <- ddply(df,.(kind,label,attribute),mutate,cum=rank(x)/length(x))

ggplot(dfx,aes(x=x))+geom_line(aes(y=cum,color=kind))+facet_grid(label~attribute)
```