# Prevent ggplot's ECDF function from splitting graphs on colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating ECDF plots using the `stat_ecdf` command from `ggplot2`. I would like to be able to specify colours for points in the ecdf with different categories.

We'll use the `iris` dataset as a toy example. When I attempt to use `aes(col=Species)` in `stat_ecdf` the plot is split into the three separate ecdfs rather than simply colouring the individual points. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris) +
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                col = Species),
            geom = "point")
```

[image: three ecdfs]

I managed to create my desired output using both the `ecdf` and `geom_point` like so:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(
  value = iris$Sepal.Length,
  ecdf = ecdf(iris$Sepal.Length)(iris$Sepal.Length),
  spec = iris$Species
)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = value, y = ecdf, col = spec))
```

[image: one ecdf]

**My question is**: is it possible to produce the second graph using the `stat_ecdf` function?

Comment: This goes against ggplot2's theoretical background. I don't think you can do better than `ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = ecdf(Sepal.Length)(Sepal.Length), color = Species))`, which is basically what you have.

Comment: Hi @Roland, thanks for your comment, do you have a link to any more information about why what I want to do goes against ggplot2's theoretical background?

Comment: Read Hadley's book if you want to learn more about The Grammar of Graphics.

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: While it's not entirely a duplicate, this one also helps to address something similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379933/plotting-cumulative-counts-in-ggplot2