# Culmulative count of discrete variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is related to [Plotting cumulative counts in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379933/plotting-cumulative-counts-in-ggplot2), but that question was dealing with a continuous variable (rather than discrete).

Here, I have a bar chart

```
set.seed(2021)
dat <- data.frame(x = c(rpois(100, 1), 7, 10))
ggplot(dat) + geom_bar(aes(x, ..count..))
```

[image]

I'm trying to plot a cumulative count with

```
ggplot(dat) + geom_bar(aes(x, cumsum(..count..)))
```

[image]

There are gaps when there are 'missing values' (i.e. when `x` is 5, 6, 7, 9).

Is there a quick and easy way to have a bar chart with gaps **filled with bars**, i.e. I will have 11 bars? I could have manually created a data frame with the cumulative counts and plot it as usual, but I'm curious if there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the variable to a factor when plotting.

`ggplot(dat) + geom_bar(aes(factor(x), cumsum(..count..)))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. I should have made my question clearer that I'm looking for a plot with the gaps filled with bars (i.e. a graph with 11 bars).

Answer (score 1):

I would not call this an "easy" approach but the only one I could come up with so solve your question:

1. Pre-summarise your dataset using e.g. `dplyr::count`
2. Fill up your dataset with the missing categories using e.g. `tidyr::complete` (To this end I first convert `x` to a factor).
3. Plot via `geom_col`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(2021)
dat <- data.frame(x = c(rpois(100, 1), 7, 10))
dat <- dat %>% 
  count(x) %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = seq(range(x)[1], range(x)[2], by = 1))) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(x, fill = list(n = 0))

ggplot(dat) + geom_col(aes(x, cumsum(n)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code, stefan. This is the approach I'm using now, but I do appreciate your code for creating the plotting dataframe. It's much cleaner than mine! Hopefully there's a quicker solution to do this with just `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll use `stat_bin` instead of `geom_bar` may be that can help..

```
ggplot(dat) + stat_bin(aes(x, cumsum(..count..)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution AnilGoyal. This works, although I prefer a solution that works on categorical `x`. I will probably also use `ggplot(dat) + stat_bin(aes(x, cumsum(..count..)), breaks = seq(-0.5, 10.5), col = 'white')` to make it more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest that but after testing